# R: Can't select a specific column in a data frame

Tags: r, select, subset

I have a problem with a function to select a given column. I have a data frame called Volume from which I want to make a subset DateSearch:

```
DateSearch = subset(Volume,select=c("TRI",name))
```

For some reason it does not work. I have used browser(). I can select TRI or name but I can't select both (either with their name or indice). I have tried with and without "".

Does anyone know why is that?

Many thanks,
Vincent

Comment: Your *select* argument is incorrect: `c("TRI", "name")`.

Comment: What is the error message you get? Or if there is no error message, in what way does the actual result differ from the expected one?

Comment: name is a variable read before with as.character()
The error message is undefined columns selected

Answer (score 1):

I just did what (I think) you describe:

```
str(dfrm)
#'data.frame':  20 obs. of  8 variables:
# $ ID     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ factor1: Factor w/ 4 levels "Not at all","To a small extent",..: 3 2 3 NA 3 NA 3 NA 4 1 ...
##   <snip>

 name = "factor1"
 subset(dfrm, select=c("ID", name))
```

No error, .... results as expected.

Examine the spelling carefully. My guess is that you have a space at the beginning or end of the result of the `as.character` result. Perhaps even a non-printing character? You can use `nchar(name)` to check.

Comment: checked: it's not that. Could the names column of my data frame be in a different type than character ?

Comment: Easy enough to check. `str(names(dfrm))`

Comment: Time to stop guessing: Need reproducible example. Use `dput` to display `head(dfrm)` and `name`.

Comment: Thanks for the head thing. My head is wird.

Comment: dput(name) return the header i thought i have. dput(head(dfrm)) returns some a part of the header, and some name linked to some vectors

Comment: Be careful. There are many possible interpretation one could put to that. ;-)